# Joomla Restricted Access with ajax.php

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

In plugin:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            $.noConflict();
            $(function(){ 
                jQuery('.aa').click(function(){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'/ajax.php',
                        data:'articleId='+articleId,
                        success: function(){
                            alert('yes');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('no');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>";
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access' . __FILE__);

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user = JFactory::getUser();


extract($_POST); 


$db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `#__c` WHERE id = "'.$articleId.'"');


$db->setQuery('SELECT a FROM `#__u` WHERE user_id = "'.$user->id.'" AND a IN ('.$articleId.')');
$a = $db->loadRowList();

$a_array = array();
if (!$a){
    $a_array[] = $articleId;        
    $combined_a = implode(",", $a_array);


    $Updatesql = "UPDATE `#__c` SET b=1 WHERE id = ".$articleId;
    $db->setQuery($Updatesql);
    $db->query();
}



?>
```

I placed the ajax.php in my joomla folder: /public_html/ajax.php

- got alert('yes'), nothing else
- inspect and see the network > clicked on the ajax.php > got "Restricted access". I think is because I have it in my ajax.php.

What can I do to have the access and execute the ajax.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy that ajax.php code here.

Answer (score 0):

To access the external file you don't need to put

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access' . __FILE__);
```

Just removed this from the script and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the first line is the reason why you're getting the message:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access' . __FILE__);
```

Is Joomla's standard way of making sure a PHP file is only accessed via the Joomla CMS framework, i.e. via it's `index.php` or `/administrator/index.php`.

Routing all requests via these `index.php` allows Joomla to do several things:

1. Make sure that PHP files are only executed when a user is supposed to have access.
2. Prevent the code from being exploited as an attack vector or as a DoS exploit
3. Provide token, session and application context to the PHP file being executed.

Point 3 is essential if you are going to use Joomla framework features like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

which return the Database object and the current user object. I'm sure you can see why not controlling access to the database or the user details is a *Very Bad Thing™*

Depending on the version of Joomla you are working with there are several different way to make AJAX call from your custom extensions to the Joomla CMS, for example in 3.2 a new "[Joomla Ajax Interface](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)" was added to expose a lot of the Joomla content.

Given the variety of methods available I would recommend reading the very good [answer provided](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/147/107) on the [Joomla Q&A StackExchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/147/107) site.